# Passing data from code behind (c#) to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have seen the below piece of code which apparently is a techiqnue to pass variables from code behind into javascript. Use either ScriptManager to register a function and pass it data during `Page_Load`:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Set","get("Test();",true);
```

Could someone please explain how this could be used to pass data?

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx)?

Comment: I have done some searches on the get/set in javascript but can't see how exactly how it works in the above way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a get or set in JavaScript, this is a startup script that will run when the DOM loads client-side. It's a basic JavaScript call to a method named `get` that receives two parameters. The first is a string, and it's getting that value passed into it by calling a method server-side named `Test`. The second is a boolean value.

Now, two things, I don't know how this is even compiling. But second, there is a method called `get` in one of your JavaScript files. That's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm guessing the "true" is supposed to be the final parameter to the RegisterStartupScript method as it takes in a addScriptTags param but yes this will not compile as is.